# How to prove that $V\otimes_{\mathfrak o}\mathfrak o_{\mathfrak p} \approx V\otimes_K K_\mathfrak p$

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $\mathfrak o$ be a Dedekind domain with field of fraction $K$, $\mathfrak p$ be one of its prime ideal, $K_{\mathfrak p}$ be the completion of $K$ at $\mathfrak p$, i.e. with respect to $| \,.|_\mathfrak p$, and $\mathfrak o_{\mathfrak p}$ be the valuation ring of $K_{\mathfrak p}$,

then for any $K$-vector space $V$:

> $V\otimes_{\mathfrak o}\mathfrak o_{\mathfrak p} \approx V\otimes_K K_\mathfrak p$ by $v\otimes_{\mathfrak o}\lambda \mapsto v\otimes_K \lambda  $ ($v\in V, \lambda \in \mathfrak o_{\mathfrak p}$)

I am not sure what type of isomorphism it is, I assume it's an $\mathfrak o$-module isomorphism.

The surjective part is easy, as for $K_{\mathfrak p}$ is $\mathfrak o_{\mathfrak p}$'s field of fraction, but why is it injective?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg How to check the inverse is well-defined? $v\otimes_K x$ may be written as many other forms.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I mean the inverse map: $V\otimes_K K_\mathfrak p  \rightarrow V\otimes_{\mathfrak o}\mathfrak o_{\mathfrak p}$, $K_p$ needs to be transformed to something in $\mathfrak o_{\mathfrak p}$, but $v\otimes_K x= v'\otimes_K x'$, I can define the inverse but don't know how to check it's well defined.

Comment: @CYC: From the information you've given I can't tell whether you don't understand how to define homomorphisms on tensor products, if your attempt to define the inverse is wrong or awkwardly done, or something else.

Comment: @Hurkyl I define the inverse in this way: $v \otimes_K \frac {a}{b} \mapsto \frac {v}{bc}\otimes ac$ for $a,b \in \mathfrak o_{\mathfrak p}$ with $c\in \mathfrak o$ and $bc \in \mathfrak o$. It's complex and I don't know how to check it's well defined.

Comment: Suppose $a'/b' = a/b$ and that $(a',b',c')$ satisfies those conditions....

Comment: @Hurkyl if $v$ is the same then I can check it, but it might be written as $v'\otimes \frac {a'}{b'}$, there is no clear relations to me how $v\otimes \frac{a}{b} = v'\otimes \frac {a'}{b'}$ relate to each other, hence I don't know how to check.

Comment: You don't need to check. Exercise: can you prove $v \otimes_\mathfrak{o} \lambda \to v \otimes_K \lambda$ is well-defined?

Comment: @Hurkyl Since tensor product is quotient of something, that quotient relation on the left hand side, generated w.r.t $\mathfrak o$ can be regard as if they were in the right hand side, hence that relations still carries after mapping. But this can't be done in the opposite.

Comment: After thinking a bit, I think that process can actually be progressed... maybe I had solved it.